# Did any Jedi besides Yoda sense when Order 66 was implemented?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, yoda

Do any Jedi besides Yoda feel pain (or shock or dismay) when other Jedi die during Order 66?

The moment when Yoda feels pain is at 2:50 to 3:00 in this video clip.

I prefer answers from D-canon over EU.

Comment: The real question is why didn't they all see it coming...

Comment: I think most of them were preoccupied at the time.... Too busy getting murdered to stop and muse on everyone else also getting murdered.

Comment: Ahsoka Tano felt a disturbance in the force, and knew something bad happened with Anakin. Then the clones on the venator attacked her.

Answer (score 4):

### Jaro Topal

In a flashback in [*Jedi: Fallen Order*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Jedi:_Fallen_Order), Jedi Master [Jaro Topal](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jaro_Tapal) senses that "something is wrong" immediately before his clone battalion is issued Order 66:

It's not made clear whether he's specifically sensing the deaths of other Jedi or the betrayal itself, but, like Yoda, he appears to stagger before his own clone attachment receives the order.